# Jenkins adds own logging statement to maven build process

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-3

I've got a problem with Jenkins building maven project. It adds some custom logging lines to regular output of build process in Maven.
When I run maven manually or by Eclipse output looks like this:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] Ana
>   [INFO] Ana APIs
>   [INFO] Ana Data
>   [INFO] Ana Webapp
>   [INFO]
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Building Ana 0.2.5-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

But when maven is started by Jenkins it looks like this:

> Jan 8, 2014 12:46:46 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger sessionStarted
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:46 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger sessionStarted
>   INFO: Reactor Build Order:
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:46 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger sessionStarted
>   INFO:
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:46 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger sessionStarted
>   INFO: Ana
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:46 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger sessionStarted
>   INFO: Ana APIs
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:46 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger sessionStarted
>   INFO: Ana Data
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:46 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger sessionStarted
>   INFO: Ana Webapp
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:47 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger projectStarted
>   INFO:
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:47 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger projectStarted
>   INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Jan 8, 2014 12:46:47 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger projectStarted
>   INFO: Building Ana 0.2.5-SNAPSHOT

There's a lot of these ExecutionEventLogger which make it harder to read maven log. How to disable this?
Jenkins ver: 1.530
Java ver: 6
Maven ver: 3
Maven goals and options in Jenkins: clean install -P$build_env $maven_parameters
where build_env = dev and maven_parameters is blank

Answer (score 2):

According to bug report [JENKINS-19396](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19396), you can't disable this. You can work around it by downgrading to version 1.525 or older, or update Maven Plugin to version 2.0 (which is now independent of the core version according to [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19396?focusedCommentId=192441&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-192441) comment in the bug report).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I learned form that and improved the answer.